# url is not opening in javascript controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am newbie to javascript and want to open a url from javascript controller, I have put my "html" code into javascript and tried as below,But it gives me error that

> ( expected after :

my code is as below,can anybuddy please tell me how can i do this.

```
var web ="http://www.google.com";
 '<ons-button class="desc" onclick="window.open('+web+');">Facebook</ons-button>';
```

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could modify it to

```
var web ='http://www.google.com';

"<ons-button class='desc' onclick=window.open('" + web +"');>Facebook</ons-button>";
```

It seemed to work.

Comment: Jigar, can you try with the edited code, if it works out for you!!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the HTML you are generating:

```
<ons-button class="desc" onclick="window.open(http://www.google.com);">Facebook</ons-button>
```

You are failing to put the URL inside a string literal. You need to generate quotes around it if you take that approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$scope` to bind variable value to `<ons-button>`.

Replace  to below code:

In Controller

```
'<ons-button class="desc" ng-click="open(web);">Facebook</ons-button>'

$scope.web = 'http://www.google.com';

$scope.open = function(web) {
  window.open(web)
}
```

Check [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaQQVG)

Comment: my html is in javascript controller,after putting your code it gives me error like `<ons-button class="desc" onclick="window.open('"+web+"');">Facebook</ons-button>` ,Expected ; but found +web+

Comment: You've lost the `'` at the ends, so it isn't a JS string any more. If you'd put them in then the `'` you added would end the string just before a `"` which is also invalid.

Comment: as i told you my BOTH code is in CONTROLLER....!!!! not in seperate html,are you getting me now?